# Feather JS vs Express JS

Tags: node.js, express, feathersjs

Recently I have been learning about Feather JS. However I am pretty much confused by the difference between Express and Feather. One of the most important reason people use Feather is because of its capability to provide real time API. Can't Express use real time as well? What are the other differences that set Feather apart from Express?

Comment: OP - Stack Overflow is for straightforward answers to straight foward questions. Your questions doesn't fit that bill. You could try at programming.stackexchange.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the docs

> Feathers is a tiny, fully compatible wrapper over Express and Socket.io

So it still uses `express` underneath.

Here am assuming, `real time` means being able to *get data as soon as it's available* (this could still be ambigous on how one defines, but yeah *rough definition*)

So, here `real time` could just mean pages getting loaded with data in *real time* (approx) using the underlying `socket.io` functionality.

So comming back to your question:

> Can't Express use real time as well?

You can very well integrate `socket.io` on your own. Or really any other `duplex` socket technologies like `websocket`, or others like `long polling`, `server-sent events` etc.

> What are the other differences that set Feather apart from Express?

This part is out of scope for SO question. But in simple terms `Feather` adds more functionality using `express` underneath.

Comment: Thanks. This answer is far better and helpful than just plain downvoting.